# Multi language CMS

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

need very simple multi lingual CMS. Currently site is in pure html. So all pages are written in pure html. No dynamics, block, etc.

What I need is: I can create 3 versions of site and add content to it. That's all.

Currently I think of Wordpress+qtranslate or TribiqCMS. But I am not sure right now.

Answer (score 1):

GetSimple CMS could be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you like wordpress I recomend WPML.

I know  it is not free, but I think it's the best option for wordpress and it worth what it cost in terms of hourly rate compared to qtranslate.

Drupal it's my second option (free but not simple). Time costs money, so choose wisely on what you know better.

Comment: Yeah I read about it, but it is not free. I'd better install some TribiqCMS or SaurusCMS, but WP is easier to edit.